# Wordpress: Get specified content from another page

Tags: wordpress, get

I want to display just a specific content from one site to another.

For example:
I want to show some text inside a `<div>` @ another page.

Page A:

```
<h2>This is page A</h2>

<div id="showonly">This is the content I want to show in footer for ex.</div>
```

Footer:
Now I want to show only the div with this specific ID.

What I did so far:

1. This is my function for getting content from a page (whole content)

   ```
   function show_post_leweb($path) {  
     $post = get_page_by_path($path);    
     $content = apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content);    
     echo $content;    
   }
   ```
2. In footer.php I did then:

   ```
   $content_leweb = show_post_leweb('kontakt');  
   echo '<div class="special-content">' .$content_leweb . '</div>';
   ```

Works fine, but I need only a certain div not the whole page, like I mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `preg_match` fro specific content from the output.

So using preg_match. put condition of start ... end div. then you will get only div content in your output.

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php for more information.

First of all make your regex less greedy by using ? operator. This will make sure you won't get more then you think you will get. The next thing is /s operator at the end of your expression. I assume you parse a HTML file which has many new line characters "\n".

```
$value=preg_match_all('/<div class=\"name\-of\-class\">(.*?)<\/div>/s',$file_contents,$estimates);
```